# 'You have an error in your SQL' syntax when trying to get object form table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an "objects" table and using hibernate 5.0.1.Final

**Here's my hibernate entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "objects", schema = "spark")
public class ObjectsEntity implements Serializable {
@Id
private int id;
@Column(name = "created_at")
private Timestamp createdAt;
@Column(name = "updated_at")
private Timestamp updatedAt;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "device_id")
private Integer deviceId;
@Column(name = "group_id")
private int groupId;
@Column(name = "icon_id")
private int iconId;
@Column(name = "photo")
private String photo;
@Column(name = "state_number")
private String stateNumber;
@Column(name = "brand")
private String brand;
@Column(name = "model")
private String model;
@Column(name = "year")
private int year;
@Column(name = "dimensions_length")
private double dimensionsLength;
@Column(name = "dimensions_width")
private double dimensionsWidth;
@Column(name = "dimensions_height")
private double dimensionsHeight;
@Column(name = "lifting_capacity")
private double liftingCapacity;
@Column(name = "fuel_сonsumption_100")
private double fuelСonsumption100;
@Column(name = "fuel_сonsumption_MT")
private double fuelСonsumptionMt;
@Column(name = "speed_display")
private String speedDisplay;
@Column(name = "stopping_time")
private int stoppingTime;
@Column(name = "parking_time")
private int parkingTime;
@Column(name = "parking_speed")
private int parkingSpeed;
@Column(name = "parking_ignite")
private byte parkingIgnite;
@Column(name = "stopping_speed")
private int stoppingSpeed;
@Column(name = "stopping_ignite")
private byte stoppingIgnite;
@Column(name = "personnel_shift")
private byte personnelShift;
@Column(name = "personnel_shift_start")
private Time personnelShiftStart;
@Column(name = "personnel_shift_end")
private Time personnelShiftEnd;
@Column(name = "fuel_сonsumption_100_max")
private double fuelСonsumption100Max;
@Column(name = "fuel_сonsumption_MT_max")
private double fuelСonsumptionMtMax;
@Column(name = "fuel_min_fill")
private int fuelMinFill;
@Column(name = "fuel_ts_fill")
private int fuelTsFill;
@Column(name = "fuel_min_drain")
private int fuelMinDrain;
@Column(name = "fuel_ts_drain")
private int fuelTsDrain;
@Column(name = "type")
private String type;

}
```

I try to call interface's method to get an object:

```
ObjectsEntity object=objectRepository.findById(report.getTransport());
```

My contoller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/report")
public class ReportController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Autowired
private ObjectRepository objectRepository;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/getReport", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<Report> getReport(
        @RequestParam (value = "report") String reportVal
){
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Report report = mapper.readValue(reportVal, Report.class);

        ReportsGenerator reportsGenerator = new ReportsGenerator(report);
        ObjectsEntity object = 
objectRepository.findById(report.getTransport());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(report);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

My interface:

```
@Repository
public interface ObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<ObjectsEntity, Long> {
ObjectsEntity findById(int id);
}
```

**And get an MySqlSyntaxErrorException**:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'?onsumption_100 as fuel_?o12_0_, objectsent0_.fuel_?onsumption_100_max as fuel_?'` at line 1

Here's the full query:

```
select usersentit0_.id as id1_1_, usersentit0_.activationCode as activati2_1_, usersentit0_.avatar_path as avatar_p3_1_, usersentit0_.client_id as client_i4_1_, usersentit0_.companyName as companyN5_1_, usersentit0_.companySite as companyS6_1_, usersentit0_.created_at as created_7_1_, usersentit0_.default_language as default_8_1_, usersentit0_.default_timezone as default_9_1_, usersentit0_.email as email10_1_, usersentit0_.isActive as isActiv11_1_, usersentit0_.name as name12_1_, usersentit0_.owner as owner13_1_, usersentit0_.password as passwor14_1_, usersentit0_.permissionAdmin as permiss15_1_, usersentit0_.permissions as permiss16_1_, usersentit0_.phone1 as phone17_1_, usersentit0_.phone2 as phone18_1_, usersentit0_.position as positio19_1_, usersentit0_.remember_token as remembe20_1_, usersentit0_.role as role21_1_, usersentit0_.socket_token as socket_22_1_, usersentit0_.summer_time as summer_23_1_, usersentit0_.updated_at as updated24_1_, usersentit0_.username as usernam25_1_ from users usersentit0_ where usersentit0_.id=?
```

Unfortunately, I can't provide smaller entity and query(I've got only two entities by now and everything is work fine with another one).

I'm using:

- spring boot
- mysql 5.7
- JDBC 4

What am I doing wrong?

Anybody know what is the exact issue

help is highly appreciated, Thanks, Shneor.

Comment: I can't spot any error in your entity so I assume it must be somewhere else. If possible please provide a [mcve]. Additionally it would be good to post the entire SQL query (and if you can with a smaller entitiy so it isn't too big) that Hibernate is generating. You should get that query if you set the logger `org.hibernate.SQL` to debug.

Comment: My guess is that it is not the character `c` in the sql statement, just something that looks very similar (such as `ç`), that is not compatible with the character set used, hence the `?` in the error message.

Comment: @Thomas I've provided entire query, controller and repository interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the letter `c` is replaced by `?` in the error message, most likely the field name has a different letter in place of the `c`. Something that looks very similar to `c`, but not the same (such as `ç`) and MySQL does not recognise it due its character set configuration.

I would change the letter to `c` in the fieldname shown in the error message.

Comment: Good thought. I just tested it by copying the posted name of one column and comparing it with a manually typed string: they look identical but are not (by terms of `String.equals()`). Printing the code points reveals that the "c" is not codepoint 99 (lowercase c) but 1089.